# Unable to catch events from EventEmitter in Angular2?

Tags: typescript, eventemitter, angular, typescript1.5

I have written a basic angular application that utilises the EventEmitter class, however i cannot get the listening component to catch the event.

Here is my code (using alpha.27 on Angular2 / TypeScript 1.5 compiling to ES5)
Apologises for the verbose example.

Any advice on what i am incorrectly doing what would be greatly appreciated.

```
import {Component, View, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    events : ['loggedIn']
})

@View({
    template: '<button type="button" (click)="submitForm()">Click Me</button>'
})

export class Login {

    loggedIn = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() { 
    }

    submitForm() {
        console.log("event fired");
        this.loggedIn.next({});
    }

}


@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})

@View({
    template: "<div>This is the application</div>"
})

export class App {
    constructor() {

    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'root'
})

@View({
  template: '<app [hidden]=!showApp></app><login (loggedIn)="loggedIn()" [hidden]=showApp></login>',
  directives: [ App, Login ]
})

export class Root {

    showApp:boolean;

    constructor() { 
        this.showApp = false; 
    }

    loggedIn() { 
        console.log("event caught");
        this.showApp = true; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried:
    (^loggedIn)="loggedIn()"  
but this has not solved the issue.

Comment: could we remove this question? it's pretty confusing, because ng2 has been updated and now neither question nor answer is not up-to-date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is [a working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/28jnf4?p=preview) of your app.

```
import {Component, View, EventEmitter, bootstrap} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'login',
  events : ['update']
})
@View({
  template: '<button type="button" (click)="submitForm()">Login</button>'
})
class Login {
  constructor() { 
    this.update = new EventEmitter();
  }
  submitForm() {
    this.update.next();
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app'
})
@View({
  template: "<div>This is the application</div>"
})
class App {}

@Component({
 selector: 'root'
})
@View({
  template: `
  <app [hidden]="!showApp"></app>
  <login (update)="loggedIn()" 
    [hidden]="showApp"></login>
  `,
  directives: [App, Login]
})
class Root {
    showApp:boolean;
    constructor() { 
        this.showApp = false; 
    }
    loggedIn() { 
        this.showApp = true; 
    }
}

bootstrap(Root);
```

I think there were a few problems. `(update)` in the template is a type of event, so it can't be called `loggedIn`. I found it easier just to call the event `update` altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Just struggled with this issue myself.

The reason it doesn't work is due to the case of the event name.  If this was named loggedin rather than loggedIn it would have been fine.

Comment: I just found that, If you want to use mixed case names for your custom events, you can use 'loggedIn' for the variable names, and 'logged-in' for the event name in the HTML.  like this ... (logged-in)="handler()"

Answer (score 3):

In the template of the Root class, you should pass $event into the loggedIn call:

```
(loggedIn) = "loggedIn($event)"
```

The $event variable represents the object that you pass in the next method of your loggedIn emitter in the Login class. Of course, your loggedIn method of your Root class should also accept an object as an argument.

Comment: Also, in the code behind of Root, you should declare:

loggedIn(obj) { 
        console.log("event caught");
        this.showApp = true; 
    }

Comment: This actually has no effect. The issue is related to the `(event)` on the left hand side being called `(loggedIn)`, when the event type is `(update)`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to decorate the class member with `@Output()`, e.g.

```
@Output() close: EventEmitter<DialogResult> = new EventEmitter<DialogResult>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [example](http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax)? Viktor Savkin uses almost everything the same as you, but without an empty object in this line:

```
this.complete.next();
```

On the AngularU, Misko has shown an example with EventEmitter: https://angularu.com/VideoSession/2015sf/angular-2-roadmap-update
starting at 41:00

Comment: If i pass through no arguments i get the following compiler error:
error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: This has no effect, you can pass an object or simply call the Event Emitter.